# How to delete row which have same value of row above in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Python with pandas library. I have the DataFrame as below

```
                       slope    decision
Date        
2019-10-31 20:38:00 -0.000062    1
2019-10-31 20:39:00 -0.000411    0
2019-10-31 20:40:00 -0.000901    0
2019-10-31 20:41:00 -0.001053    1
2019-10-31 20:42:00 -0.001213    1
... ... ...
2019-10-31 23:54:00 -0.000103    0
2019-10-31 23:55:00 -0.000035    0
2019-10-31 23:56:00 -0.000143    0
2019-10-31 23:57:00 -0.000233   -1
2019-10-31 23:58:00 -0.000305   -1
```

Now I would like to delete any row that continously have same value as the row right below it. Just keep the row where it have a change in value of 'decision' column as the desired below

```
                       slope    decision
Date        
2019-10-31 20:38:00 -0.000062    1
2019-10-31 20:39:00 -0.000411    0
2019-10-31 20:41:00 -0.001053    1
... ... ...
2019-10-31 23:54:00 -0.000103    0
2019-10-31 23:57:00 -0.000233   -1
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare for not equal with [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) values created by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) for mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['decision'].ne(df['decision'].shift())]
```

Or compare if difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) is not `0`:

```
df1 = df[df['decision'].diff().ne(0)]
```

---

```
print (df1)
                        slope  decision
Date                                   
2019-10-31 20:38:00 -0.000062         1
2019-10-31 20:39:00 -0.000411         0
2019-10-31 20:41:00 -0.001053         1
2019-10-31 23:54:00 -0.000103         0
2019-10-31 23:57:00 -0.000233        -1
```