# Pandas group in series

Tags: python, pandas, series, group

Given

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1], 'value':['a','b','c','d','e']})
```

I need to treat **a** and **b** as one group, **c** as second group, **d** and **e** as third group. How to get first element from every group?

```
pd.DataFrame({'group': [1, 2, 1,], 'value':['a','c','d']})
```

Comment: Hi How you distributing the groups ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
df1 = df[df['group'].ne(df['group'].shift())]
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59136415/13174934) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified if the `group` column tells whether the values are considered to be in the same group. So I'm assumming it has no connection, and you specify your groups in the `groups` list:

```py
groups = [['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e']]

condlist = [df['value'].isin(group) for group in groups]
choicelist = list(range(len(groups)))
group_idx = np.select(condlist, choicelist)

df.groupby(group_idx).first()
```

**Result:**

```py
   group value
0      1     a
1      2     c
2      1     d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your groups and map them to a reduced output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1], 'value':['a','b','c','d','e']})
groups = [['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e']]
mappings = {k: i for i, gr in enumerate(groups) for k in gr}

print(
    df.groupby(df['value'].map(mappings)).first()
)
       group value
value             
0          1     a
1          2     c
2          1     d
```